# Does View Location doesn't work in ReactiveUI in net core project?

Tags: .net-core, reactiveui, avaloniaui

I tried to use View Location https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/view-location/  in my net core Avalonia (https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia) project. I register View as IViewFor in the container. But view still doesn't resolve on my window. Also, I search in sources of ReactiveUI and looks like it functionality doesn't work for net core yet. Am I right?

Answer (score 3):

The [Avalonia.ReactiveUI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Avalonia.ReactiveUI/) package doesn't include a registered implementation for the `ViewModelViewHost` control at the moment of writing this post. Currently, the recommended approach of working with data templates and user controls with `ReactiveUI` and `Avalonia` is writing somewhat like this:

```
<ListBox.DataTemplates>
    <DataTemplate DataType="interfaces:IFileViewModel">
        <views:FileView DataContext="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.DataTemplates>
```

Where `FileView` is declared as a `ReactiveUserControl<IFileViewModel>`.

```
public sealed class FileView : ReactiveUserControl<IFileViewModel>
{
    public FileView()
    {
        this.WhenActivated(disposables => { /* Handle activation here */ });
        AvaloniaXamlLoader.Load(this);
    }
}
```

See [related documentation](http://avaloniaui.net/docs/reactiveui/). You can also create your own `ViewModelViewHost` implementation [based on ViewModelViewHost for Windows Presentation Foundation](https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/master/src/ReactiveUI/Platforms/windows-common/ViewModelViewHost.cs#L28), and register it using [ReactiveUI service location](https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/dependency-inversion/), if the approach described above won't suite you. [Avalonia.ReactiveUI package sources](https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/tree/master/src/Avalonia.ReactiveUI) may help.

If you are using ReactiveUI routing, then the good news is that it fully supports Avalonia, see [routing and activation with ReactiveUI and Avalonia documentation](http://avaloniaui.net/docs/reactiveui/). `RoutedViewHost` is working properly and will resolve `IRoutableViewModel`s and embed appropriate views for you.

Comment: We added a `ViewModelViewHost` in some of the latest Avalonia.ReactiveUI builds btw.